# x:Name doesn't work in XAML Flyout control

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I tried the following in a Windows 8.1 C# app:

```xml
<!-- XAML file -->
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Label="Add News Feed" Icon="Add">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <StackPanel Width="400">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter Text:" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="inputTextBox"/>
                        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

```cs
// C# file
private void AddButon_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = inputTextBox.Text;
    // Do something with the text
}
```

However, when I run my app and click the Add button I get a System.NullReferenceException because the member inputTextBox is null. I checked and the generated InitializeComponent method has the following line:

```cs
inputTextBox = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)this.FindName("inputTextBox");
```

I even tried changing my event handler to call FindName in case the control was created when the Flyout was shown and it still returns null. Why can't FindName find my text box?

**Update: Workaround**

I was able to get to the TextBox using the VisualTreeHelper as shown below:

```cs
TextBox textBox = null;
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as Button);
var numChildren = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
{
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as FrameworkElement;
    if (child != null && child.Name == "inputTextBox")
    {
        // Found the text box!
        textBox = child as TextBox;
        break;
    }
}

if (textBox != null)
{
    var text = textBox.Text;
    // Do something with the text
}
```

If this is indeed confirmed as a bug in Windows 8.1 preview I'll go ahead and close out this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the 8.1 preview and we hope to have this issue addressed in the final version of 8.1

Joe

Comment: I figured out to use the VisualTreeHelper to find the textbox. I'll post the workaround in an update to my question.

Comment: @Skippy - I know this because I'm on the product team.

Comment: @JoeStegman I am still seeing this issue even after release. Has it been addressed?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the VisualTreeHelper method, you can alternatively create a subclass of Flyout and attach that to your UI element with Flyoutbase.SetAttachedFlyout(UIElement, FlyoutSubclass);

```
class ForgotPasswordFlyout : Flyout
{
    StackPanel contentPanel = new StackPanel();
    public Thickness margins = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10);

    public Button forgotPasswordButton;
    public ProgressBar forgotPasswordProgressBar;
    public TextBlock forgotPasswordMessageTextBlock;
    public TextBox forgotPasswordTextBox;

    public ForgotPasswordFlyout()
    {
        forgotPasswordMessageTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        forgotPasswordMessageTextBlock.Text = "Enter the email address you used to register.";
        forgotPasswordMessageTextBlock.Margin = margins;
        contentPanel.Children.Add(forgotPasswordMessageTextBlock);

        forgotPasswordTextBox = new TextBox();
        forgotPasswordTextBox.PlaceholderText = "Email";
        forgotPasswordTextBox.Margin = margins;
        contentPanel.Children.Add(forgotPasswordTextBox);

        forgotPasswordButton = new Button();
        forgotPasswordButton.Content = "Recover Password";
        contentPanel.Children.Add(forgotPasswordButton);

        forgotPasswordProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
        forgotPasswordProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        forgotPasswordProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        contentPanel.Children.Add(forgotPasswordProgressBar);

        this.Content = contentPanel;
    }
}
```

Now, we can't access the textbox directly because x:Name doesn't work. However, in the view controller we can register events for these UI elements.

```
private void RecoverPasswordCommandButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ForgotPasswordFlyout forgotPassFlyout = new ForgotPasswordFlyout();
        forgotPassFlyout.forgotPasswordTextBox.TextChanged += forgotPasswordTextBox_TextChanged;
        forgotPassFlyout.forgotPasswordButton.Click += forgotPasswordFlyoutButton_Click;
        FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(RecoverPasswordCommandButton, forgotPassFlyout);
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(RecoverPasswordCommandButton);
    }
```

This way we can directly access the Textbox when the event fires off and save the text for use.

```
void forgotPasswordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox forgotPasswordTextBox = sender as TextBox;
        ForgotPasswordFlyout.forgotPasswordEmail = forgotPasswordTextBox.Text;
    }
```